# Assign object property to listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ArrayList` of an object which has properties `Object.name` and `Object.url`.

I want to loop through the ArrayList and apply the Object's "name" to an android ListView. I also want to keep the Object's other properties in tact, so that i can call the "url" property in the onClick method.

What i have now is this:

```
main_list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<RomDataSet>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mRoms));
```

But clearly that is not what I need...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.) You have your ArrayList:

```
main_list
```

2.) Create a ListView in your XML file (say, main.xml) and grab its id. That is, given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/liveFeed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do something like this:

```
ListView livefeed = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.liveFeed);
```

within your activity (if you're in somewhere else such as an OnClickListener, replace the "this" with the View variable that was passed as a variable into the OnClickListener).

3.) Define your ArrayAdapter. Note that one of its parameters (the third one in your case) will be a TextView id. This is because the ArrayAdapter class, by default, returns a TextView in the ListView. If you override the ArrayAdapter class, you can use custom layouts to have items with custom Views within your ListView, but this is not necessary for what you've outlined in your question, and it seems like you've got it already.

4.) Set the adapter to the ListView (given an ArrayAdapter named 'aa'):

```
livefeed.setAdapter(aa);
```

Now the way the ArrayAdapter works is it invokes each Object's toString() method and sets each TextView in the ListView to this String. So make a toString() method in your Object's class that returns its name property:

```
public String toString(){return name;} //assuming name is a String
```

Also note that, if you add Objects to the ArrayList, notify the ArrayAdapter that you have so it can accordingly update your ListView with the modifications (given an ArrayAdapter named 'aa'):

```
aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Let me know if you need any more help. As always, check the answer check mark if this answered your question.

Also note that, at one point you may wish to cross reference your ArrayAdapter and ArrayList between your activity and Object class. It's very helpful to make these fields static in order to do so.

EDIT:

You wanted to also know how to access a specific Object when you click on an item in the ListView. Here it is (given your ListView is named livefeed):

```
livefeed.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

    //in here you may access your Object by using livefeed.getItemAtPosition(position)
    //for example:
        Object current = livefeed.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //do whatever with the Object's data
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, so i've overridden the toString() method of my object, and that worked great in displaying the name in the listview. Now what i'm still confused on is how to access the selected listviewitem (object)'s properties (name, url, other properties) and say, pass them in an intent to another activity? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Glad it helped! So, as I understand it, each Object has a URL and you would like for each item in the ListView to open up the browser to that URL onClick right? Also note that the properties of the Objects are still in tact. All the Objects are still in your ArrayList.

Comment: well, i tried to simplify it in the example, but each object has a name, url, description, and an image. I then want to pass this data to another activity in which it will display it :) So i'm fairly sure i just need to pass it as intent extras, however i'm not sure how to access the object from the onClick method. Sorry, as you can tell i'm new to android development :)

Comment: So why don't you detail *exactly* what you want to do. I'll help you out. And it's all good. I was new to Android development not too long ago haha.

Comment: Basically I have list of game roms that i have parsed from the net into rom objects. Each has a name, url, description, rating and image. I have the object list where i need it, and have applied the name to the listview from what you told me. Now when i click on the list item, i want to trigger a onClick listener, get the object that was selected, then pass it to the next view (i know how to pass it). Then i just need to apply the object's fields to various places in the new activity, which i'm fairly sure i'll be able to do (or at least work it out) :) Thanks man

Comment: Oh ok so you literally just need to know how to access the Object from the onClickListener. In that case, given your ListView is named livefeed, I've added to my answer above to show you how to access your specific Object OnClick.

Comment: Awesome, thanks mate! I'm not sure if i can see the changes yet though?

Comment: They're up there. ^^^^^ :-) I only appended more info to the answer.